# Get closest coordinate in 2D array

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, coordinates, python-itertools

```
coordinates = [(-225.0, -299.5), (-150.0, 75.5), (0.0, 0.0), (225.0, 300.5)]

xy = (-222.4, -204.5)
```

What is the best way so that a given value xy can be compared to a 2D list of coordinates, and return the index number of the closest coordinate?

In this example, xy would be compared to the coordinates list and thus return the closest coordinate (-225.0, -299.5) or, more ideally, the index number 0.

I've tried researching for a method with itertools or numpy, but couldn't seem to understand how to get the result I want in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#min) with a proper `key` function. Sth along the following lines for instance:

```
coordinates = [(-225.0, -299.5), (-150.0, 75.5), (0.0, 0.0), (225.0, 300.5)]
xy = (-222.4, -204.5)

dist = lambda x, y: (x[0]-y[0])**2 + (x[1]-y[1])**2
min(coordinates, key=lambda co: dist(co, xy))
# (-225.0, -299.5)
```

Comment: I would suggest using [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) instead—it's probably faster.

Comment: @martineau I don't quite see how the distance from the origin helps in this general distance case.

Comment: `min(coordinates, key=lambda p: math.hypot(p[0]-xy[0], p[1]-xy[1]))`

Comment: @martineau So you are adding an extra function call and still doing calculations in pure Python? Not too convincing....

Comment: Timing the execution is the only definitive way to tell. Doing so, I found that for larger numbers of points, your way is about 19% slower than using `hypot()` with Python 3.7.1. Here's the [benchmark](https://pastebin.com/fP4Zh6WC) used to determine this (results are at the very end).

Answer (score 4):

Using scipy.spatial.KDTree:

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np
coordinates = [(-225.0, -299.5), (-150.0, 75.5), (0.0, 0.0), (225.0, 300.5)]
x = [(-222.4, -204.5)]
distance,index = spatial.KDTree(coordinates).query(x)
print(distance)
print(index)
```

The kd-tree method is O(N*log(N)) and is much faster than Brute Force method that takes O(N**2) time for large enough N.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is equivalent to : How do I sort a Python list using a custom method to define the sorting key. This can be done in raw python without using external libraries.

When using the `sorted()` function of python you can pass a lambda to the `key` argument to get the sort done on a specific key.

From there you just have to define the key as your own distance calculation method (here using the distances between the points):

```
from math import *
coordinates = [(-225.0, -299.5), (-150.0, 75.5), (0.0, 0.0), (225.0, 300.5)]
xy = (-222.4, -204.5)
results = sorted(coordinates, key= lambda v: sqrt(pow((v[0] - xy[0]), 2) + pow((v[1] - xy[1]), 2)))
# Output : [(-225.0, -299.5), (-150.0, 75.5), (0.0, 0.0), (225.0, 300.5)]
```

From there you can just take the first element of the list if you want the closer point, etc. If you still want to external module I think you can use some third parties function such as `from scipy.spatial import distance` as the key parameter of the sort.

Comment: Sorting a list with a custom key function involves quite a bit more processing than simply finding the list element that produces the minimum when passed to that functiont—so, no, the question isn't equivalent to that. If it were, I would suggest using the `math.hypot()` function because it's faster that the way you're doing it. See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257607/get-closest-coordinate-in-2d-array/53257770#comment93421254_53257770) about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a function that iterates through the list of coordinates and keep the index of the one in which the distance between two points is the smallest (using the Pythagorean theorem).

However, if you need something fast given by an external module rather than writing your own, I am not aware of libraries I already used that already have that function, so I'm not helpful here.

Comment: I thought about this, but wouldn't the Pythagorean theorem not work if I have negative and positive coordinates in my list? e.g. if coordinates = [(-255.0,-255.0), (255.0,255.0)] -> it wouldn't know which coordinate is closer?

Comment: @Ben There is no issue with negative coordinates, Pythagoras will still take good care of the correct distance. You just have to decide on a tie breaker if in deed, two sets of coordinates havce the same distance.

Comment: If you have negative and positive coordinates it will surely work, the formula doesn't care if you have positive or negative coordinates. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Euclidean_distance_in_various_coordinate_systems)

If the distance from a specific point from two other points is the same, it will take the index of the first point that appears on the list.